# Is there a way to caught signal when GtkEntryCompletion popped up?

Tags: c, gtk

I have an application with a `GtkEntry`.

As a feature of the program, I use key-press-event signals on this entry `for GDK_KEY_Up`, `GDK_KEY_Down`, `GDK_KEY_Return` and `GDK_KEY_KP_Enter`. But the thing is I would like to disable these homemade functions when the `GtkEntryCompletion` shows completion popup items, in order to navigate in the completion list with the two arrows and to validate with entry keys.

To do this, I need a signal to tell me when I need to disable the homemade `key-press-event`, but the only signal availables with `GtkEntryCompletion` are:

```
void        action-activated
gboolean    cursor-on-match
gboolean    insert-prefix
gboolean    match-selected
void        no-matches
```

Maybe there's another way to do it.

EDIT: I would like something equivalent to `popup-shown` from `GtkComboBox` I guess.

Comment: If you don't find the right signals, then just follow the inheritance tree. All signals from parents are available.

Comment: I do agree but I do not see which one could help.